# Add Row Button adds PHP cell with Select2 option

Tags: javascript, php

Sorry about the Q form but I couldn't find a better way to explain it.

I have a view table that have drop down form that retrieves its options from the DB to be inserted, and it have an add button to add new row to insert.

But the drop down works on [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) forms, and it's included in the table, so every time I try to add new row it gives it the same **id** as the previous one and that conflicts with the JS for the Select2 as it needs to get special **id** for every drop down I made with it.

***here's the table and the add button code***

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="tab_logic">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Brand Name</th>
                            <th>Item Name</th>
                            <th>Model Number</th>
                            <th class="col-md-2">Item Description</th>
                            <th>Part Number</th>
                            <th>Unit</th>
                            <th class="col-md-1">QTY</th>
                            <th class="col-md-1">Unit Price (SR)</th>
                            <th class="col-md-1">Total Price (SR)</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Record</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Record</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Record</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <?php
                                        $query = $con->query("SELECT products_itemDescription FROM pruc_products"); // Run your query --> For Item Desc.
                                        echo '<select class="form-control" id="DescriptionS2forms" name="itemDescription">'; // Open your drop down box

                                        echo '<option value="" selected="selected" disabled></option>'; //Empty Value for VALIDATION
                                        // Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one
                                        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                           echo '<option value="'.$row['products_itemDescription'].'">'.$row['products_itemDescription'].'</option>';
                                        }
                                        echo '</select>';// Close your drop down box
                                     ?>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Record</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Record</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="requestQTY" required>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="requestUnit" step="0.01" min="0.01" max="1000000" required>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <strong>Record</strong>
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-1" id="deleteBtn">
                                <a class="btn btn-default deleteBtn">Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End of 3rd Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Add</a>
        </div>
```

***And the JS for the add button and select2 function:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    var i = 0;
    $("#add_row").click(function() {
        var x = '[{<td><strong>Record</strong></td>      <td><strong>Record</strong></td>      <td><strong>Record</strong></td>      <td><div class="form-group">  <?php $query = $con->query('SELECT products_itemDescription FROM pruc_products'); echo '<select class="form-control" id=DescriptionS2forms'.(i+1).'" name="itemDescription">'; echo '<option value="" selected="selected" disabled></option>'; while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {echo '<option value="'.$row['products_itemDescription'].'">'.$row['products_itemDescription'].'</option>';} echo '</select>'; ?>  </div></td>      <td><strong>Record</strong></td>      <td><strong>Record</strong></td>      <td><div><input class="form-control" type="number" name="requestQTY" required></div></td>      <td><div><input class="form-control" type="number" name="requestUnit" step="0.01" min="0.01" max="1000000" required></div></td>      <td><strong>Record</strong></td>       <td class="col-md-1" id="deleteBtn"> <a class="btn btn-default deleteBtn">Delete</a></td>}]';

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '">' + x + '</tr>');
        i++;
    });



    $("#SupplierS2forms, #ProjectS2forms, #WHS2forms, #DescriptionS2forms").select2(); });
```

in the PHP option it gives the id="DescriptionS2forms"
so I need to add a number for the id so I can use it in the Select2 Function as it doesn't accept same id

**Example**

`id="DescriptionS2forms1"` AND `id="DescriptionS2forms2"`

Comment: Instead of using ID you can use CLASS attribute of select2 

i.e.
<select class="select2" id="select1">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>


<select class="select2" id="select2">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".select2).select2()
});

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd
it didn't work, every time I add a new row also doesn't effect it to the Select2